# Avro: Is there a java implementation to serialize a large record that does not fit in-memory?

Tags: java, memory, size, avro

I'm pretty new to avro and am trying to evaluate its potential as a "container" for hdfs file contents.
I do know about SequenceFiles but would like a language agnostic file format if possible.

From the java api it seems like all object serialization occurs in-memory, which seems to bound potential record size to the amount of available memory.  Is there another java workaround or implementation that I'm not seeing?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of any serialization which is purely in memory only.  All of them support a byte stream API or similar. This works where you would serialise small portions at a time e.g. 8 KB.

Comment: I think my problem might be avro specific. It's not the writing of the object that is the problem per se, but the need to construct the object in memory before you can write it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Now you know one ;) More seriously each record has to fit in memory, no partial/lazy/chunked reading or writing. Available memory is a strict upper bound. If you plan to use it in Hadoop MR it is even worst than that. Hadoop uses various ByteArrayOutputStream or buffer when you write a <KEY, VALUE> it means that you have the 2^31 bytes limitation and IIRC it was even worst than that.

Comment: @ClémentMATHIEU Sounds pretty broken. Even the built in serialization is Input/OutputStream based.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Avro is quite similar to the built in serialization (and almost any other library). You provide a POJO or they return a POJO, so the POJO has to fit in memory. Avro also support GenericData, but it is the same everything will be loaded in maps/arrays. IIUC it was OP's concern and Avro is not better or worst than built-in, pb or thrift on this point. I don't think you want to use theses tools to handle very large record that you want to only partially load. Reading from, or writing to, streams allows is to not require twice the memory and Avro obviously does this.

Comment: What do you mean by a record?  It is true that a single object must fit in memory, however not all records need to be in memory at once.  If you use streaming serialization you can read a record, process it and then read the next record. Not all records are in memory at once.

Comment: @PeterLawrey We agree. A container contains zero or more objects. Theses objects can be: primitive types, record or array. In Avro a Java object maps to [a record](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/spec.html#schema_record). OP's question contains the word record without plural, I assume he wants to store a large object. There is obviously no issue storing large collections of objects.